# scrapy splash login formdata input array name

Tags: python, scrapy

No puedo hacer el login de un formulario por que el nombre de los inputs esta como array, ejemplo:

```
<input name="login[username]" value="" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="Dirección de email" type="text">
```

y

```
<input name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="Contraseña" type="password">
```

Estoy intentado hacerlo así:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath='//form[@id="login-form"]',
        formdata={
            'login[username]': 'miuser',             
            'login[password]': 'sderdserxxxx'
        },
        callback=self.start_requests_action
    )
```

y no me funciona. ¿Alguien podría decirme como hago para pesarle los `names` correctamente o como hacerlo con `id` del `input`?